# Wide figure in a 2 column document (figure* doesn't work)

Tags: floats, two-column

I am new to this environment, but I believe I have checked other questions related to mine problem, still couldn't find a solution.
What I want is to have a wider figure in a two column document. I am trying to use

```
\begin{figure*}
\end{figure*}
```

Program gives an error. I have included all the packages I know. What else could the problem be?

Thanks

Here is the document class statement

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{IEEEtran}
```

Here are the packages I am including

```
\usepackage{ifpdf}
\usepackage{cite}
\ifCLASSINFOpdf
   \usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\else
\fi
\usepackage[cmex10]{amsmath}
\interdisplaylinepenalty=2500
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{mdwmath}
\usepackage{mdwtab}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\usepackage[tight,footnotesize]{subfigure}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{stfloats}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
```

Here is a part of the figure that I would like to have as a one column.

```
\begin{figure*}
\begin{tikzpicture}[snake=zigzag, line before snake = 5mm, line after snake = 5mm]
%draw horizontal line
\draw (0,0) -- (6,0);
\draw[snake] (6,0) -- (8,0);

%draw vertical lines
\foreach \x in {0,2,5,8}
   \draw (\x cm,3pt) -- (\x cm,-3pt);
%draw nodes
\draw (0,0) node[below=3pt] {$ t_0 $} node[above=3pt] {$   $};
\draw (1,0) node[below=3pt] {$  $} node[above=2pt] {$ h_1 $};
\draw (2,0) node[below=3pt] {$ t_1^1 $} node[above=3pt] {$  $};
\draw (3.5,0) node[below=3pt] {$  $} node[above=2pt] {$ h_2 $};
\draw (5,0) node[below=3pt] {$ t_2^1 $} node[above=3pt] {$ $};
\draw (5.75,0) node[below=3pt] {$  $} node[above=2pt] {$ h_3 $};
\draw (7.25,0) node[below=3pt] {$  $} node[above=2pt] {$ h_N $};
\draw (8,0) node[below=3pt] {$ t_N^1 $} node[above=3pt] {$ $};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[snake=zigzag, line before snake = 5mm, line after snake = 5mm]
%draw horizontal line
\draw (0,0) -- (6,0);
\draw[snake] (6,0) -- (8,0);
%draw vertical lines
\foreach \x in {0,3,5,8}
   \draw (\x cm,3pt) -- (\x cm,-3pt);
%draw nodes
\draw (0,0) node[below=3pt] {$ t_0 $} node[above=3pt] {$   $};
\draw (1.5,0) node[below=3pt] {$  $} node[above=2pt] {$ d_1 $};
\draw (3,0) node[below=3pt] {$ t_1^2 $} node[above=3pt] {$ $};
\draw (4,0) node[below=3pt] {$  $} node[above=2pt] {$ d_2 $};
\draw (5,0) node[below=3pt] {$ t_2^2 $} node[above=3pt] {$  $};
\draw (5.5,0) node[below=3pt] {$  $} node[above=2pt] {$ d_3 $};
\draw (6.1,0) node[below=3pt] {$ t_3^2 $} node[above=3pt] {$  $};
\draw (7.25,0) node[below=3pt] {$  $} node[above=2pt] {$ d_M $};
\draw (8,0) node[below=3pt] {$ t_M^2 $} node[above=3pt] {$ $};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure*}`
```

But when I use figure* instead of figure at the end it gives ;

[image]

Comment: Please add a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. In your situation, additional information about the errors (at least a transcript of the error message) could also prove useful.

Comment: "Program gives an error" is rather unspecific. Could you at least report the error message you're getting -- preferably together with an MWE that gives rise to the  error message?

Comment: Including all the packages you know may well be problematic if you know of many packages since they are likely to conflict with each other!

Comment: Package `subfigure` is deprecated, use `subfig` or `subcaption` instead. And *please* read the link on preparing a MWE.

Comment: Oh, you are right, I should have been more careful, sorry about my bad looking post.
But I am not using any subfigure or caption, it still gives the same error. Actually, with or without that package, it is the same

Comment: If you are not using subfigre, why are you loading the package? Kick it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in the order with which you load the packages: `stfloats` (assuming you really want to use it) should go before `fixltx2e` or the float will disappear.

I get no error from your minimal example, however, only the disappearance of the float.

Note however that

```
\ifCLASSINFOpdf
   \usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\else
\fi
```

is useless; just do `\usepackage{graphicx}`. The option `[cmex10]` to `amsmath` shouldn't be used as it is for compatibility with very old TeX distributions.

The packages `mdwtab` and `mdwmath` are unmaintained and likely to conflict with other packages. Also `subfigure` is obsolete; use

```
\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}
```

and change `\subfigure` into `\subfloat` in the document.

Comment: Changing the order really worked, thanks a lot. I didn't know the order matters.