# stfloats, twocolumn, figure* broken with late pdfTeX 1.40.16

Tags: floats, pdftex

I tried to build some older document with a new pdfTeX version and encountered very strange errors of figures getting lost. I was able to produce the following minimal example:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{stfloats}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}
\framebox{Hello Star}
\caption{Hello Star Figure}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

I receive the following output, and no document.

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015/Arch Linux) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./figurestar.tex
LaTeX2e <2015/10/01> patch level 2
Babel <3.9m> and hyphenation patterns for 79 languages loaded.
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/sttools/stfloats.sty) (./figurestar.aux)
(./figurestar.aux) )
No pages of output.
Transcript written on figurestar.log.
```

Earlier versions (1.40.15 and 1.40.14) do create a document. The most puzzling aspect for me is that it does not yield any error message whatsoever. Is this a bug in pdftex or strfloats? This is very annoying because it means a lot of work to be able to build old documents that were building just fine in previous versions.

Comment: P.S. What is the policy for posting the full log here?

Comment: as a workaround, you can load `\usepackage[2012/01/01]{latexrelease}` before loading `stfloats`.

Comment: You should contact the author of stfloats. Imho the problem is that stfloats should go before fixltx2e as mentioned here http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/196487/2388, and this isn't possible in newer latex versions which includes fixltx2e.

Comment: Note that the version of pdflatex is not relevant, the change is that you are using a newer latex, `LaTeX2e <2015/10/01> patch level 2`

Comment: Thank you for the very helpful comments. I have contacted the author of `stfloats` and he is looking into the issue.

Comment: @deimi: And how do I switch back to current latex release after loading stfloats?

Comment: @Stephen: I don't think it's possible to switch back to current release. As for stfloats package, there is already an updated version on ctan that is compatible with current latex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just uploaded to CTAN improved stfloats.sty package version v2.0 with support and extra adds for newer LaTeX release from 2015/01/01. 
Extra adds: float output keeps order for the same type of floats even with bottom dblfloats and puts dblfloats on the same page where they are defined in case they are defined on left column and there are available enought free space. New version is vailable on CTAN and TeXLive SVN repository.